# Using Promises to iteratively delete items in IndexedDb

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, indexeddb

I'm a bit new to promises here so the solution may be trivial / syntactical.

My goal when storing media is to see if a quota is set and - if needed - delete items from the `store` until we have space.

My attempt is here, but my biggest pain point is that `while` loop - figuring out how to wait until an item is deleted to re-evaluate whether or not to continue deleting:

```
   const store = database.transaction(storeName, "readwrite").objectStore(storeName);
   while (storageUsedInGb > storageQuotaInGb) {
       // problem: pause loop here
       const latestMediaRequest = store.get(latestMediaGuid);
       latestMediaRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
              var deleteRequest = store.delete(latestMediaGuid);
              deleteRequest.onsuccess = function () {
                    storageUsedInGb -= event.target.media.size / 1024 / 1000 / 1000;
                       // problem: continue loop here
              }
              deleteRequest.onerror = reject;
        }
        latestMediaRequest.onerror = reject;
    }
```

How can I tell that while loop to wait to iterate until I have a resolution from the `latestMediaRequest` and then the `deleteRequest` (updating `storageUsedInGb`)?

Comment: Can you use `async`/`await`?

Comment: @Bergi I can't :/

Comment: Then you need to use recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop asynchronously with a function you call recursively. The function can be an immediately invoked function expression:

```
const store = database.transaction(storeName, "readwrite").objectStore(storeName);
(function loop(storageUsedInGb) {
    if (storageUsedInGb <= storageQuotaInGb) {
        // if you are in a promise constructor callback, you will call resolve() here
        return; // exit chain of loop calls
    }
    const latestMediaRequest = store.get(latestMediaGuid);
    latestMediaRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
        var deleteRequest = store.delete(latestMediaGuid);
        deleteRequest.onsuccess = 
            loop.bind(null, storageUsedInGb-event.target.media.size / 1024 / 1000 / 1000);
        deleteRequest.onerror = reject;
    }
    latestMediaRequest.onerror = reject;
})(storageUsedInGb); // call immediately
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying edit - I am.  Trying this now.